# Programmatically created directory not showing and word file inside not openning

Tags: c#

I have a desktop app I created a word document inside a new directory in startup path.

```
string origFileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\Declerations\\file.docx";
string newName = "@'"+origFileName+"'" ;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ( newName );
```

I also have an install shield setup project. After creating the setup and installing the system and running the app, the above code doesn't open the word document. Word app runs but it displays a message saying, "Directory name invalid". I checked if the directory and file are created using `File.Exists` and they exist. But neither the directory nor the file are showing in Programfiles execution path. What is the problem that the creted directory isn't showing and the file not running?

Comment: Somewhat related to your question: Alsways use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to combine paths. That way you don't have to think about how many `\` you have to include at what point.

Answer (score 0):

Hy

have you tryed this?:

```
string origFileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Declerations\file.docx";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ( origFileName );
```

Comment: Yes I did. And it's not working. And why is the created directory not showing up in the installation path?